# Number format exception error

Tags: android

I receive number format exception error..Have to compare the values which is stored in DB as string values..value of "percent" in below code will be like +10.05% or -10.05%,"percentabove" value will be like 11.05 and "percentbelow" value will be 10.00..

Code:

```
percentabove = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.PERCENTABOVE));
 percentbelow = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.PERCENTBELOW));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        double newprice= Double.parseDouble(percent);
        double maxprice = Double.parseDouble(percentabove);
        double minprice = Double.parseDouble(percentbelow);


        if(newprice>maxprice || newprice<minprice)
        {

            String status="";
            if(newprice>maxprice)
            {
                status="Up";
            }
            else if(newprice<minprice)
            {
                status="Down";
            }
```

Have to change the format double to other datatype format..Can we use Decimalformat?any suggestions..

Comment: have you check what you got with this?  double newprice= Double.parseDouble(percent);

Comment: Please edit your question with real examples of the strings you are tying to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NumberFormatException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) clearly states that this exception is:

*Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.*

Like indicated in the comment, have you tried to explore the values `percent`, `perceabove`, `percentbelow`? Perhaps the values need some cleaning (trimming the values, removing additional commas etc.)